# determine if two IP addresses can communicate

Tags: python, ip

I have to verify if two IP addresses can communicate. I also have to take in consideration if the first IP is in a higher subnet. I have managed to check if the IP s are in the same network by importing netaddr (python), but i got stuck.

Comment: Try ping from one machine to other. With python you may write a simple client server program. Also expose '0.0.0.0' on server side when you are writing the client server program.

Comment: I suspect this is probably more a theoretical 'Homework'-style question than an actual real situation. Also not all devices connected to an IP network will respond to a PING request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always check if the IPs could theoretically *communicate* to each other by checking if the IP address are in the same network / range. This can be simply achieved by using the **Python 3.3** module `ipaddress`. Here a little example where I create two instances of `IPv4Address` and one `IPv4Network` instance. Using this standard library module you can simply check if the instances of `IPvAddress` are in the instance of `IPv4Network`.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ip1 = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')
>>> ip2 = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.2')
>>> ip3 = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.1.1')
>>> net = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')
>>> ip1 in net
True
>>> ip2 in net
True
>>> ip3 in net
False
>>>
```

Please be aware that the module ipaddress only arrived with ***Python 3.3***.

Another thing to keep in mind this does in **no way guarantee** that the IP address you've specified can actually communicate to each other. Maybe there are some firewall rules in place on the specific machines or in the network. This is only a theoretical approach and does by no mean apply to real life.